# Use Javascript to Detect OS and Include External HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I need to detect a user's OS, then include HTML from another file depending on which OS the user has. The rebuilt site has jQuery scripts from the old site that need to be kept, so my attempts partially utilized that. They don't have to.

When I try to run my script, nothing is displayed. I am new to JS.

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

if (OSName = "Windows") {
  $(function(){
      $("#downloadsection").load("apple_download_include.html"); 
    });
} else if (OSName = "MacOS") {
  $(function(){
      $("#downloadsection").load("windows_download_include.html"); 
    });
} else if (OSName = "UNIX") {
  document.getElementById("downloadsection").innerHTML= "<a class="'btn btn-labeled btn-danger me-sm-3 fw-bold mt-3'" href="'download.php#unix_distros'" role="'button'"><span class="'btn-label'"><i class="'fa-brands fa-linux'"></i></span> Download v<span class="'current-version'"></span></a>";
} else if (OSName = "Linux") {
    document.getElementById("downloadsection").innerHTML= "<a class="'btn btn-labeled btn-danger me-sm-3 fw-bold mt-3'" href="'download.php#unix_distros'" role="'button'"><span class="'btn-label'"><i class="'fa-brands fa-linux'"></i></span> Download v<span class="'current-version'"></span></a>";
} else {
    document.getElementById("downloadsection").innerHTML= "<a class="'btn btn-danger btn-lg px-4 me-sm-3 fw-bold mt-3'" href="'download.php'" role="'button'">Download v<span class="'current-version'"></span></a>";
}
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Could you clarify? If you mean using == and === in the if/then statements, I tried that.

Comment: In all of your `if` statements you're performing an assignment, not a comparison. E.g. `if (OSName = "Windows")` should be `if (OSName == "Windows")` or `if (OSName === "Windows")`

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: I didn't say it was the answer. I'm just pointing our a fundamental problem in your code. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` on the line below `else if (OSName = "UNIX") {`

Comment: I got rid of the error by escaping with backslashes instead of apostrophes. Which is odd since going over it I did escape the quotation marks. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following.

```js
var OSName = "unknown";
var navApp = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
switch (true) {
  case (navApp.indexOf("win") != -1):
    OSName = "windows";
    break;
  case (navApp.indexOf("mac") != -1):
    OSName = "apple";
    break;
  case (navApp.indexOf("linux") != -1):
    OSName = "linux";
    break;
  case (navApp.indexOf("x11") != -1):
    OSName = "unix";
    break;
}
console.log(OSName, navApp);

if (OSName == "windows" || OSName == "apple") {
  $("#downloadsection").load(OSName + "_download_include.html");
} else {
  var link = $("<a>", {
    class: "btn btn-labeled btn-danger me-sm-3 fw-bold mt-3",
    role: "button",
    href: "download.php#unix_distros"
  }).appendTo("#downloadsection");
  $("<span>", {
    class: "btn-label"
  }).appendTo(link);
  $("<i>", {
    class: "fa-brands fa-linux"
  }).appendTo($("span.btn-label", link));
  $("span.btn-label", link).append(" Download v<span class='current-version'>0.0.1</span>");

  if (OSName != "unix" && OSName != "linux") {
    link.toggleClass("btn-label btn-lg px-4");
    $(".fa-brands", link).remove();
    link.attr("href", "download.php");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="downloadsection"></div>
```

This uses `switch()` which is just an organized form of multiple `if` statements. It simple performs the code snippet for the matched case.

I corrected all logical operators and condensed the code. No reason to repeat the code for the same items.

Regarding `navigator.appVersion`:

> **Deprecated:** This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible

`navigator.userAgent` is supported by all browsers. See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent

Comment: Will the shift to Client Hints affect userAgent in the future?

Comment: Thank you! Sad to say it doesn't work and the console gives me `Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform`

Comment: @BenjaminMorrison what are your testing environments? I am using Linux with FireFox and it worked properly for me.

Comment: MacOS in Brave, Chrome and Safari all tested. There is a draft of the site here. https://shatteredsite.com/transmissiontest/index.php

Comment: @BenjaminMorrison you have a lot of Script blocks and it does not make sense why you have all this code spread out all over the place. I would suggest you consolidate your code so you can make sure there are not rogue variables or other elements causing issues. I would also make more use of `console.log()` to review the content and variables through the code. Something is not lining up.

Comment: @BenjaminMorrison remember that `.indexOf()` is Case Sensitive, so it if the browser responds with "mac" instead of "Mac" it will not match. It is best to adjust them both to Upper or Lower case when you test to ensure that you get the proper hit.

Comment: Thank you. I am simply patching this together, OOP is not my strong suit so I don't know any best practices. I spread things out for simple legibility and my own ability to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

As others in the above comments pointed out - replace = with == or === in your if statements. As a single = is an assignment operator.

please refer to the JavaScript's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Also the strings in your assignments are incorrect. If you are using double quotes to enclose the whole string then use only single quotes inside. Or vice versa.

your string assignment will look like this then:

```
document.getElementById("downloadsection").innerHTML= "<a class='btn btn-labeled btn-danger me-sm-3 fw-bold mt-3' href='download.php#unix_distros' role='button'><span class='btn-label'><i class='fa-brands fa-linux'></i></span> Download v<span class='current-version'></span></a>";
```